# Using T4MVC with build script

Tags: model-view-controller, nant, t4mvc

Has anyone gotten T4MVC to run as part of a build script ? Preferably a NAnt build script.

I'd like to not have to check in the generated files and just have the build server create them as part of the build, but T4MVC will only run inside of Visual Studio.

I've tried:

- http://devtalk.dk/2010/03/11/How+To+Run+T4MVC+On+Build.aspx
- http://otac0n.com/blog/2010/12/23/Pain-Free-T4MVC.aspx

Has anyone successfully gotten a solution to work ?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you'll be able to make this work. T4MVC relies heavily on the DTE object model, and that [simply is not available outside of VS.](http://www.olegsych.com/2010/04/understanding-t4-msbuild-integration/)