# Run T4MVC transformation from command-line

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4, t4mvc

I'm happy to [found a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062171/publish-asp-net-web-site-from-command-line-bat-file-the-ultimate-bat-file) to publish my ASP.NET MVC app from command-line, but I want to run T4MVC transform before build from .bat file too.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This came up in this previous question: [Using T4MVC with build script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372067/using-t4mvc-with-build-script).

Unfortunately, this just isn't possible due to the DTE dependency.